# How do you write .Net plugins for NSClient++

Tags: c#

I've been trying to find some examples or documentation for writing [.Net plugins](https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/windows/DotnetPlugins.html) for [NSClient++](http://www.nsclient.org).

Can someone direct me to a working sample application or some documentation?

I found the source code for the [CSharpSamplePlugin](https://github.com/mickem/nscp/tree/master/modules/CSharpSamplePlugin) on GitHub. Since I don't use CMake, I made a new VS2013 project and added the three DLL's referenced in the CMake setup to my project (`Google.ProtocolBuffers.dll`, `NSCP.Core.dll`, and `NSCP.Protobuf.dll`). I found the DLLs in the NSClient++ installation dir.

However it seems like the code in SamplePlugin.cs doesn't work with the current DLLs. I get an error on the line:

```
response.AddLines(Plugin.QueryResponseMessage.Types.Response.Types.Line.CreateBuilder().SetMessage("Hello from C#").Build());
```

... saying:

```
Error   2   'Plugin.QueryResponseMessage.Types.Response' does not contain a definition for 'Types'  C:\vs_projects\NSClientHelpers\NsClientPlugin\SamplePlugin.cs   45  74  NsClientPlugin
Error   1   'Plugin.QueryResponseMessage.Types.Response.Builder' does not contain a definition for 'AddLines' and no extension method 'AddLines' accepting a first argument of type 'Plugin.QueryResponseMessage.Types.Response.Builder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\vs_projects\NSClientHelpers\NsClientPlugin\SamplePlugin.cs   45  22  NsClientPlugin
```

So is there any place where I can find an updated sample plugin or example of how to make NSClient++ plugins?

After struggling with this for a while I just rewrote my commands as two standalone executables, but it irks me that I couldn't get this to work ;)

Comment: Asking for recommendations on SO is off-topic. Instead, it would be better to just ask about the problems you are having

Comment: I need a link to a sample that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the creator of NSClient on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/703024/problems-with-nsclient-and-net-modules). Short answer is that the code in the master branch is not compatible with the previous release. After checking out the sample code from the release tag and placing the resulting DLL in the "modules/dotnet" folder, I could add my plugin to the INI file ...

```
[/modules]
DotnetPlugins = 1 

[/modules/dotnet]
sample=CSharpSamplePlugin.dll
```

... and see it all work with `nscp test`:

```
...
D       core Loading plugin: DotnetPlugin
L            Webserver port is: 1234
...
check_dotnet
D            Got command: check_dotnet
L        cli OK: Hello from C#
```